# rake assets:precompile failing without a useful error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to precompile my assets, but whenever I try it fails with an error, but doesn't tell me anything other than that so I have no idea where it's coming from or how to find it. I'm running `rake assets:precompile --trace` and getting the following output

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile
/home/nginx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby /home/nginx/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile:all (first_time)
** Execute assets:precompile:all
** Invoke assets:precompile:primary (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke tmp:cache:clear (first_time)
** Execute tmp:cache:clear
** Execute assets:precompile:primary
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Command failed with status (1): [/home/nginx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bi...]
```

That is the full output, I've not cut anything out. As you can see, I'm just getting an error but no location or anything else.

Is there some way I can easily track this down?

Comment: what gems do you have in your Gemfile under the `:assets` group? Are you only getting this error when you compile the assets or when you run the application too?

Comment: It runs fine locally (in development env). Under assets I've only got the normal : `sass-rails`, `coffee-rails`, `uglifier` and I've added `angularjs-rails` as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out..well sort of.
So I know roughly why I was getting the error but still not the actual reason for the error and which file it was :(

But basically, I have altered the files that are precompiled by rails, and the method I was using was causing all css files to be precompiled regardless of whether I was importing the files into `application.css.scss` or not.

This was then leading to some of the SASS mixins not being found, and for some reason, having the asset compression settings that I have, caused me to simply get the error I originally posted.

Once I'd disabled the compression, I got a more helpful error which eventually lead me to the final solution.

Thanks :)

Comment: more detail would be nice, for others. What files did you alter that are precompiled by rails? What method were you using? What SASS mixins were not being found? What asset compression did you have, causing the error? What helpful error did you get? What was the final solution?